# MD5 Merkle–Damgård construction in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, hash, md5

I have a column which contains the MD5 hashes of some unknown data.

I need the MD5 hash of "that unknown data, concatenated with another string".

I *think* that the Merkle–Damgård construction means that there should be a function which I can use to pipe some more plain-text into the hash, without knowing the original plain-text.

Does such a function exist for MD5?

What is is called in Postgres?  I've only found `MD5(plain-text)`.  I need `MD5extend(md5hash, extra-plain-text)`.

I think that what I'm trying to do is a "length-extension attack".

Comment: Yes such a function exists for md5, and it is rather trivial to implement, but such function doesn't naturally exist *in* Postgres, as it is not generally useful - only for attacks. Notice that the concatenation doesn't work *as is*, but it will necessarily have the length and the padding of the original message in between.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the padding - this wrecks the idea.  Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.